# Lua singleton when re-requiring

Tags: lua

Let's say I have some wrapper for some class:

```
local wrapper = {}
local some_library = require('some-library')

wrapper._library = some_library.new(...)

return wrapper
```

If I `require` my wrapper in different files, will a new instance of `some_library` be created every time? i.e

```
// file1
local file1 = {}
local wrapper = require('wrapper')
-- add methods to file1
return file1

// file2
local file1 = require('file1')
local wrapper = require('wrapper')
```

And then I do `lua file2`

In this case, `wrapper` is included twice; once inside `file1` which `file2` is requiring, and once by `file2` itself. Will there be two instances of `some-library` now? How do I create a singleton if I only want one instance?

Comment: don't use `local` when you want something to be global. Basically it should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369646/do-file-only-once-in-lua

Comment: Trying to call `require` again shouldn't work.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176681/import-mutiple-lua-files-at-once

Comment: @Konrad but I don't want to define `wrapper` to be global. I want to import it whenever I want into the scope of a file. If I don't have `local`, then `wrapper` becomes a global variable.

Comment: Did you test your code? Does it work?

Comment: @Konrad that's not necessarily a good advice. Using `local` whenever possible avoids polluting the global environment and *can* improve speed. In fact, that's precisely what `require` is for; you *should* require things multiple times and *should not* require something into a global variable because at some other place in the code something different may be required into that same global var, breaking your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

## no

[Long answer](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers):

When you `require` a file, lua first checks if the module has already been loaded. If not, it loads (executes) the file and saves its return value into a global table where it's cached. This means that a) some-library is only required **once** and b) the same happens for the wrapper, so you only have *one* wrapper for *one* library; as opposed to several wrappers to one library or several wrappers with individual libraries.

Keep in mind though: if your *module* returns not the library code, but a function that then creates the library code, only the function is cached, but every time you run it it returns a different copy of your library object. For example:

```
-- lib.lua
return function()
  { foo = function(bar) print("fooing a bar...") end }
end

-- program.lua
factory_1 = require "lib"
factory_2 = require "lib"

print(factory_1 == factory_2) --> prints "true"

lib_1 = factory_1()
lib_2 = factory_1() -- not a typo, it's factory_1 called twice

print(lib_1 == lib_2) --> prints "false"
```

And if you're *really* bored, you can create a library (as a table) that, when called as if it were a function (using the `__call` metamethod) returns a new instance of the library just like the first one.